# What is another way to say my concern?

Tags: synonyms

I voiced concerns on way things were being carried out in a fashion that was understood as a disgruntled parent. I intended the information to be taken in a way to indicate concern or issue for all involved on a not personal or selfish way.

Comment: How about 'affair' or 'issue'?

Comment: I thought about using issue, but I felt it still conveys personal attachment. I feel like I need to change the verbiage from my to something else... maybe the quandary?

Comment: You offered to elaborate on an opportunity for improvement?

Comment: the conversation was concerning a program for children. I thought I voiced concerns for the program direction, function, and handling. I was after approached in conversation because I was "extremely disgruntled." In trying to rectify this misunderstanding I realize I cannot use "my concern" because I do not want to portray possession or expressed claim of the issues at hand.

Comment: Saying "I have a concern about X" is perfectly legitimate, and not, in itself, offensive.  Of course, any time you express displeasure over the way that others are running some program they are apt to react negatively.  You must anticipate that and attempt to phrase things "gently".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to say that you "voiced your concerns" but got dismissed as a "disgruntled parent" because you were too "personally invested"?  Or something like that?

The common way to avoid this is to use the collective.  "*We* have a problem."  "*Our* students are in trouble."

Without more context it's difficult to give more exact political language, but something like this should be a good start:

> I bring this up because *our* students are lacking in ...